# Cyclic Hamming Code

Tags: coding-theory

I know that Hamming codes can be arranged in cyclic form. But my question is how can I proof this.

My idea was to find a generator/primitive polynomial $p(x)$? For example I want to show that the $[15,11]$ Hamming code can be written in a cyclic form. Then the generator polynomial $p(x)$ must divide $x^{15} +1$ . The factorization of this is: $x^{15} +1=(x+1)(x^2 +1)(x^4 +x+1)(x^4 +x^3 +1)(x^4 +x^3 +x^2 +x+1)$ . But what is now my $p(x)$ and why?

And what is the next step in my proof?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The generator polynomial of a cyclic binary $[2^n-1, 2^n-1-n]$ Hamming code
is always a *primitive* polynomial of degree $n$. So, use one of the two
*primitive* polynomials of degree $4$ that you have exhibited as factors of
$x^{15}-1$.  (Hint: you may need to first figure out which two of the three
polynomials of degree $4$ are primitive and which one is nonprimitive).

Thus there are *two* different cyclic binary $[15,11]$ Hamming codes depending
on which primitive polynomial you choose as the generator polynomial.
They are related in the sense that if
$(C_0, C_1, \ldots, C_{14})$ is a codeword in one code, then
$(C_{14}, C_{13}, \ldots, C_1,C_0)$ is a codeword in the other code.

Comment: Okay... Using the Magma Calculator, I think that $f_1(x)=(x^4+x+1)$ and $f_2(x)=(x^4+x^3+1)$ are primitive polynomials of degree 4, because then I have Parituy Check Matrices with all independent column vectors.

Comment: But how can I proof that all $[2^n-1,2^n-1-n]$ are equivalent to a cyclic (Hamming) Code? Thus not for the case that $n=4$ but for all $n$?

Comment: The columns of the $n \times (2^n-1)$ parity check matrix of _any_ binary Hamming code are the $2^n-1$ nonzero binary vectors. _Permute the columns_ so that they occur in the order in which they are found in the parity check matrix of _your_ choice of cyclic Hamming code

Comment: But what is the 'normal' order of the columns in the parity check matrix, before you permute it in the way you want? And how can I proof that there is Always such a permutation?

Comment: There is no normal order; there are $(2^n-1)!$ different orders in which you can list the $2^n-1$ nonzero binary vectors of length $n$.  **Each** such order gives a **different** binary Hamming code. **Some** of these Hamming codes are cyclic. So, **pick** one of the cyclic Hamming codes and look at its parity check matrix. Can you find **two or more** identical columns? Yes? No? If not, the columns are all distinct and are just the $2^n-1$ nonzero binary vectors of length $n$ in a specific order. **Now** prove that there is a permutation of columns that changes one matrix into the pther.

Comment: Nice, it becames more and more clear. But how can I prove that there are/is always some that is cyclic?