# When are Hamming codes cyclic?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, finite-fields, coding-theory

**Motivation**

The following statement appears to be true:

> The $q$-ary Hamming code of codimension $r$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ is equivalent to a cyclic code if and only if if $q-1$ and $r$ are coprime.

See for example [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3141372/61691) by Dietrich Burde as a in-house quotation.

The $\Leftarrow$-direction is not too hard to show (making use of a primitive element of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q^r}$), but I could not find a proof for the other direction anywhere. I've checked various sources like web search, search on this page math.stackexchange, as well as standard books on coding theory like MacWilliams-Sloane, van Lint or Huffman-Pless.

**Question**

> Assume that $q-1$ and $r$ at not coprime. Show that the $q$-ary Hamming code of codimension $r$ is not equivalent to a cyclic code.

---

Dietrich Burde pointed me to the book of Huffman & Pless, "Fundamentals of Error-Correcting codes", 2003. I checked this book again, but I cannot find the full desired statement nor a proof. The closest things I can find are:

Theorem 5.1.4 on page 169 shows that for $\gcd(r,q-1) = 1$, the $q$-ary Hamming code of codimension $r$ is a narrow-sense BCH code, which gives "$\Leftarrow$".

Corollary 5.1.5 on page 170 observes that as a consequence, all binary Hamming codes are primitive narrow-sense BCH codes.

Example 5.1.6 shows that the $[4,2,3]$ ternary Hamming code is not cyclic, which is close to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3141351/61691). Part of the reasoning is left as the subsequent Exercise 288. (In my opinion, the direction proposed by Huffman and Pless using the automorphism group of order $48$ is unnecessarily complicated. Better observe that there are only two cyclic ternary $[4,2]$ codes and their generator polynomials have weight only $2$.)

I certainly did not check the whole book, but I could not find anything else. If the statement indeed was there, I would expect a pointer at Theorem 5.1.4 orExample 4.1.6 to the general statement.

Comment: I think this follows from a study of the check matrix (or check polynomial) of such a code. Cyclicity forces the check matrix to have a single row with entries the powers $\alpha^i$, of a root of unit $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_{q^r}$ of order $n=q^{r-1}+\cdots+q^2+q+1$, $i=0,1,\ldots,n-1$. For the resulting code to be a Hamming code we need the "columns" $\alpha^i$ to be pairwise linearly independent over $\Bbb{F}_q$. This is so if and only if $\langle\alpha\rangle$ intersects trivially with the subgroup  $\Bbb{F}_q^*$ if and only if $\gcd(q-1,n)=1$ if and only if $\gcd(q-1,r)=1$.

Comment: I need to sort out a few things in my head (and tend to non-math things) before I can flesh that out to an answer. I do think that's the way it can be shown, but leaving it as a comment for now. Leaving the stage open for other answerers also.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen wow, only 1 hour after I'm asking your are thinking about my little problem. I agree that thinking about the check polynomial $h$ should be the natural approach. The rows of the check matrix are given by the coefficient sequences of $h, Xh, \ldots, X^{r-1}h$. Now the columns must be pairwise linearly independent. Basically, this is how the opposite direction is done, with the additional step that the columns are identified with the elements of the extension field $\mathbb{F}_{q^r}$. I'm a bit puzzled how to do the identification in this general situation.

Comment: A general proof of this result can be found in W. C. Huffman and V. Pless, Fundamentals of error correcting codes, Cambridge
University Press, 2003 - this is claimed at least.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you. I did check Huffman-Pless when asking this question, and I've checked it once again now, see the addition to my question. I cannot find the statement.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen this is just to tell you about the bounty. I'm just trying to avoid that it will be wasted in the end :)

Comment: Thinking... There is a complication if the dual code is not a minimal cyclic code. You're right in that MacWilliams-Sloane and van Lint don't have anything about the difficult direction.